# Zend 2 Fieldset InputFilterSpecification break on failure

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-inputfilter

I have a fieldset implementing the Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface interface but I'm unable to specify for an element to breaks on failure during validation.

To give an example :

```
public function getInputFilterSpecification()
{
    return array(
        'target_id' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'allow_empty' => true,
            'continue_if_empty' => true,
            'break_on_failure' => true,
            [...]
        ),
    );
),
```

Am I missing/mistyping something ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was using Zend 2.2.5 and this problem has been patched in 2.2.6 => https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/pull/5691